# Flexible number of form fields in Django forms

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates, formsets

I would like to create a form that contains several fields like this

```
class MainForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='name')
    comment = forms.CharField(label='comment')
```

Right now we have one field "comment".  Now I want to have the option that a user can add more comment fields to the form through the website.

So I need to:

1) Define the form more flexible such that there can be N comment fields. (Default is N=1)

2) Define a method to add new comment fields.

3) Define utility functions, like cleaning form fields, so flexible that they can handle the dynamic number of comment fields.

I would like get some ideas of how to set this up in a clean way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found something that works for me and I want to at least post the rough draft of what I did.

First, I indeed found percent20's suggestion of using django formsets very helpful.  My forms.py looks roughly like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from django.forms.forms import NON_FIELD_ERRORS

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField(label='comment')

class MainForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='name')

    def __init__(self):
        self.commentFormset =  formset_factory(CommentForm, extra=1)
        self.comments = self.commentFormset()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MainForm, self).clean()

        for nForm, commentForm in enumerate(self.comments):
            if commentForm.is_valid():
                pass
            else:
                self._errors[NON_FIELD_ERRORS] = self.error_class(['Invalid Comments'])
```

Here is the relevant part of my views.py

```
from forms import MainForm

def commentView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MainForm(data=request.POST)
        form.comments = form.commentFormset(data=request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        # ...
        for commentForm in form.comments:
            if commentForm.is_valid():
                # do some stuff with each comment
    else:
        form = MainForm()

    template = loader.get_template('main.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, { 'form': form })

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

I found the following great jquery plugin: http://blog.stanisla.us/2009/10/10/jquery-plugin-django-dynamic-formset/.
This enables me to give the user the opportunity to add and delete comment fields.  No extra code needed in view.py or forms.py.

Here is the relevant snippet from my template.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery.formset.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $('tr.comment-form').formset( { prefix: 'form' });
    })
</script>

 <div id="commentSection">
    Comments:
    <table>
        <tbody>
          {{ form.comments.management_form }}
          <th>Comment</th><th></th>
          {% for commentForm in form.comments %}
          <tr class="comment-form">
            <td>{{ commentForm.comment.errors }}{{ commentForm.comment }}</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Formsets are a good solution for this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/

It will handle 1 and 3 cleanly. I have had to write javascript in the past to inject extra fields in the form when clicking add. Then after submit django takes care of the rest.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

So you suggest defining 'comment' as a formset?  And you say that if a form with, say 5 comment fields, is submitted, django would group them together as a formset?

Comment: Yes, that is effectively what I am saying. However, you have to name the forms specifically, and the docs discuss how to do that so the default and custom Django validation works on each one. I did this with a recipe builder where I had to allow users to keep adding ingredients.